I Can't Create Stripe Connect
I have a problem when trying to create a Connect in Stripe, Stripe requires me to authenticate my account and do some other steps, then I can create the Connect. The problem here is that Stripe requires a bank account and ID of a specific person, but Stripe does not support it in Vietnam and banks in Vietnam, I do not have a foreign bank and do not have citizenship of another country. I tried filling in fake information but that didn't work.
Anyone who has a solution please help me, I would like to thank you very much!




Please contact https://support.stripe.com/?contact=true they are equipped to guide you through the creation of an Express Connect Account in Vietnam
